# Dynamic Json File for Java Objects

Tags: java, json, serialization, dynamic, objectmapper

I have a java class model which have getter/setter method along with enum type.
I want to expose JSON file along with all the fields, by default one fields have values and other fields are null.

How can I create dynamic file by using java model class.

```
package com.manifest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
   "@id",
   "@type",
   "dct:identifier"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class DctMediaType {

/**
 * 
 * (Required)
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("@id")
private String id;
/**
 * 
 * (Required)
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("@type")
private DctMediaType.Type type;
@JsonProperty("dct:identifier")
private String dctIdentifier;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * 
 * (Required)
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("@id")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * 
 * (Required)
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("@id")
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public DctMediaType withId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
}

/**
 * 
 * (Required)
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("@type")
public DctMediaType.Type getType() {
    return type;
}

/**
 * 
 * (Required)
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("@type")
public void setType(DctMediaType.Type type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public DctMediaType withType(DctMediaType.Type type) {
    this.type = type;
    return this;
}

@JsonProperty("dct:identifier")
public String getDctIdentifier() {
    return dctIdentifier;
}

@JsonProperty("dct:identifier")
public void setDctIdentifier(String dctIdentifier) {
    this.dctIdentifier = dctIdentifier;
}

public DctMediaType withDctIdentifier(String dctIdentifier) {
    this.dctIdentifier = dctIdentifier;
    return this;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

public DctMediaType withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    return this;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(DctMediaType.class.getName()).append('@').append(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))).append('[');
    sb.append("id");
    sb.append('=');
    sb.append(((this.id == null)?"<null>":this.id));
    sb.append(',');
    sb.append("type");
    sb.append('=');
    sb.append(((this.type == null)?"<null>":this.type));
    sb.append(',');
    sb.append("dctIdentifier");
    sb.append('=');
    sb.append(((this.dctIdentifier == null)?"<null>":this.dctIdentifier));
    sb.append(',');
    sb.append("additionalProperties");
    sb.append('=');
    sb.append(((this.additionalProperties == null)?"<null>":this.additionalProperties));
    sb.append(',');
    if (sb.charAt((sb.length()- 1)) == ',') {
        sb.setCharAt((sb.length()- 1), ']');
    } else {
        sb.append(']');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 1;
    result = ((result* 31)+((this.id == null)? 0 :this.id.hashCode()));
    result = ((result* 31)+((this.dctIdentifier == null)? 0 :this.dctIdentifier.hashCode()));
    result = ((result* 31)+((this.additionalProperties == null)? 0 :this.additionalProperties.hashCode()));
    result = ((result* 31)+((this.type == null)? 0 :this.type.hashCode()));
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((other instanceof DctMediaType) == false) {
        return false;
    }
    DctMediaType rhs = ((DctMediaType) other);
    return (((((this.id == rhs.id)||((this.id!= null)&&this.id.equals(rhs.id)))&&((this.dctIdentifier == rhs.dctIdentifier)||((this.dctIdentifier!= null)&&this.dctIdentifier.equals(rhs.dctIdentifier))))&&((this.additionalProperties == rhs.additionalProperties)||((this.additionalProperties!= null)&&this.additionalProperties.equals(rhs.additionalProperties))))&&((this.type == rhs.type)||((this.type!= null)&&this.type.equals(rhs.type))));
}

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public enum Type {

    DCT_MEDIA_TYPE("dct:MediaType");
    private final String value;
    private final static Map<String, DctMediaType.Type> CONSTANTS = new HashMap<String, DctMediaType.Type>();

    static {
        for (DctMediaType.Type c: values()) {
            CONSTANTS.put(c.value, c);
        }
    }

    Type(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String value() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static DctMediaType.Type fromValue(String value) {
        DctMediaType.Type constant = CONSTANTS.get(value);
        if (constant == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(value);
        } else {
            return constant;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Need my JSON output file like below:

```
{
 "@id":null,
 "@type":"dct:MediaType"
 "dct:identifier":null
}
```

I tried below way but I'm getting empty json object {}.

```
ObjectMapper dynamicMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 dynamicMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
 dynamicMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.ALWAYS);
 String jsonValue = dynamicMapper.writeValueAsString(new DctMediaType());
```

Please suggest some guidance to create dynamic json file creation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you both have the `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`  annotation which is telling the serializer to skip any NULL values and removing the properties from the JSON output, and you are never initializing the fields to any non-null value in your bean.

You are passing `new DctMediaType()` into the mapper, but never setting any of the fields.

It sounds like if you *want* the nulls in the JSON then you should change the annotation to `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)`

Comment: Above class dynamically generated from Json schema, we can't override json annotation in model class. If we change json schema the above class generate automatically with updated attribute.

Answer (score 0):

By using below code I can able to achieve solution for my use-cases.

```
Class<?> clazzObj = Class.forName("com.manifest.DctMediaType");
                JsonObject tempObj = new JsonObject();
                for (Field newField : clazzObj.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    if (newField.isAnnotationPresent(JsonProperty.class)) {
                        String annotationValue = newField.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class).value();
                        String childTypeString = newField.getGenericType().toString();                          
                            tempObj.add(annotationValue, "");

                        }
                      }
```

My Output:

```
 {
    "@id": "",
    "@type": "dct:MediaType",
    "dct:identifier": ""
}
```